# Call a function inside a class method and use its variables

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to PHP, i made some research but couldn't find a clear answer.
In a ***functions.php*** file i have a *function* that contains some variables that i need, and a ***classes.php*** file containing a class with a method that needs the values from the variables of the *function* in ***functions.php***.
**The Question is: why the echoed variable is outputted but the other variables are called as Undefined.And how can i call and use them.**

### Example:

functions/functions.php

```
<?php
// functions.php file

function incFunc(){
    $inc_var1 = "Marco";
    echo $inc_var1; //this variable output Marco without problem
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    $inc_var2 = "Polo"; //this is the variable i want to use in the class method.
}
?>
```

classes/classes.php

```
<?php
// classes.php file

include '../functions/functions.php';
class theClass
{   
    public function classFunc(){
        incFunc();
        echo $inc_var2; //Notice: Undefined variable: inc_var2
    }
}
$obj = new theClass();
$obj->classFunc();
?>
```

**Outputs:**

Marco

Notice: Undefined variable: inc_var2 in...

Comment: functions have their own scope - all you do is execute the first function, where you echo the first var inside the first function.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i couldn't find or i guess i have missed out to find the answer in other already existing questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use variables from incFunc function scope in the class you have to return the value
Example:

```
function incFunc($returnVar){
   $inc_var1 = "Marco";
   $inc_var2 = "Polo";
   if ($returnVar == 'var1') {
      return $inc_var1;
   } else {
      return $inc_var2;
   }
}
```

Than,in your class method, save the result of a function in an variable:

```
public function classFunc(){
    $inc_var1 = incFunc('var1');
   // do stuff
}
```

This is just a basic example, if you want to include multiple variables at once, you can return an array instead of single variables.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question its just what i was asking.